# How to convert this php code in C#

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0, sugarcrm

```
   'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
              array(
                   'name' => 'email_addresses',
                   'value' => array(
                        'id',
                        'email_address',
                        'opt_out',
                        'primary_address'
                   ),
              ),
         ),
```

I have the above code in PHP and its working fine with sugarcrm but what i want is to create similar code in c# so that i can get the same data using c#.

Comment: So you want to write in `C#`? Title should be `How to convert this php code in C#`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should create the same structure as yours, but I think there is another way to handle our needs in C#. If you provide some more code we could help more.

```
object[] link_name_to_fields_array = new object[1] 
{ 
    new object[2, 2] 
    { 
        { "name", "email_addresses" }, 
        { "value", new string[4] 
            { "id", "email_address", "opt_out", "primary_address"} 
        } 
    } 
};
```